# Installing without losing files

Tags: system-installation

I'm currently using the Windows 7 and I want to replace the whole thing with Ubuntu. How do I do that without losing my music and my movies?

Answer (score 0):

First of all backup all those file to another drive that means save those music files or folder in a drive other then C drive assuming Windows is installed in C Drive then go for installation.

Make a bootable USB or DVD as explained on the Official Download Page for Ubuntu .

Go into Bios and change the first boot priority to either USB or DVD , whichever you are using to install ubuntu from.

Insert you DVD or USB Stick and restart , it will ask you to choose either **Try Ubuntu** or **Install Ubuntu** in that click on Install Ubuntu.

then it will ask for installation type in that choose **Replace Windows7 with ubuntu** as shown below -

[image: here]

then press continue and provide the simple informations like date ,user name, and passwork.

Advice never select Encryption Option if you dont know what it is , not important for at all.

hope i have explained everything you want to know.

Comment: @Mitch in first two lines i have mentioned to make backup by copying them into another drive other than the drive in which Windows 7 is installed.